# Creating a 3d numpy array matrix using append method

Tags: python, numpy, memory, arrays

Is there a way to create a 3d numpy array by appending 2d numpy arrays? What I currently do is append my 2d numpy array into an initialized list of pre determined 2d numpy array, i.e., List=[np.zeros((600,600))]. After appending all my 2d numpy arrays I use numpy.dstack to create 3d numpy array. I think this is not a very efficient method. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is to initialize the 3d array first and then sequentially write your data into it. Efficiency here is increased by avoiding unnecessary copies. The gains are however minimal - as long as you are not working with very large arrays (in either of the 3 dimensions).

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.empty(shape=(2, 100, 100))

arr[0,:,:] = array_2d_1
arr[1,:,:] = array_2d_2
```

Answer (score 1):

By definition you cannot append anything to an array because when the array is declared in memory it has to reserve as much space as it is going to need.

What you can do is to either declare an array with the known geometry and initial values and then rewrite the new values per row keeping a counter of the rows "appended" or you can double the size of the array when you run out of space.